# How to find and replace a particular unicode character with a non-unicode character in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, replace, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am being provided a string that may have a unicode apostrophe in it (\u2019) and I must replace it with a standard apostrophe (plain old "'"). I usually use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to do this kind of thing but trying this does not work:

```
sMyString = [sMyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u2019" withString:@"'"];
```

Makes sense that it didn't work I guess since the actual values representing the apostrophe internally in the NSString will be numeric.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does the string have an actual `’` character or does it have the characters \, `u`, `2`, `0`, `1`, and `9`?

Comment: When I use po sMyString in Xcode's console it appear as an actual ' character, though curved as you have shown it.  However, when that string is part of a dictionary and I use po to print out the dictionary it displays the sequence, so Mama's boy looks like: Mama\u2019s boy.  That's how I discovered it actually.

Comment: Logging a dictionary results in `\uxxxx` output for lots of characters. That's just a stupid decision by Apple to confuse developers. Sounds like your string has the actual quote character. My posted answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sMyString` has the actual `’` character then either do:

```
sMyString = [sMyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2019" withString:@"'"];
```

or:

```
sMyString = [sMyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@"'"];
```

Both of these actually compile to the same code. The `\u2019` is replaced by `’` during compilation.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Dang.  I had the extra backslash in there which is why it wasn't finding it.  Removed it so it looked like your code and worked like a champ.  Many thanks.

Comment: With the extra backslash, the match will only work if the string contains the actual text `\u2019`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sMyString = [sMyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\U2019" withString:@"'"];
```

Do not use `\U2019`, it makes an error.

Comment: Use \u2019 instead of \U2019. I was using \U2019 it gives error Incomplete universal character name.