# stringByReplacingOcurrencesOfString with special character objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I am trying to replace instances of 's with s or alternatively instances of s with 's.  However, the result of the code below is an empty string.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
NSString *myStr = @"Eat at Joe's";
 NSString *newStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'s" withString:@"s"];
//edited as per Vadian
NSLog(@"newStr:%@",newStr); //logs as newStr:
```

Comment: That was a typo in my question now corrected.  The original has the placeholder.

Comment: The code is supposed to work.

Comment: My xcode crashed.  I will try again when it reboots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the placeholder

```
NSLog(@"newStr: %@", newStr);
```

Don't you get the warning

> Data argument not used by format string

Comment: Curious why this was accepted as the correct answer since the question (after fixing the typo) includes this same line of code already. So this doesn't actually fix anything.

Comment: The answer is correct..literally. I think the real reason my code did not work was Xcode got corrupted as after xcode crashed and I restarted mac it worked properly.  You are not supposed to delete questions with answers otherwise I would have deleted this question.

Comment: It is also possible the error in my app had to do with apostrophes in IOS 11 and onward. For my question, I wrote the string as a ' using the keyboard but in the app it comes from user input where apple substitutes smart apostrophes.  Here is a question you answered on this very topic.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304347/how-to-find-and-replace-a-particular-unicode-character-with-a-non-unicode-charac